Need help configuring a /56 prefix
I have requested my ISP to provide me with a /56 prefix. They came and replaced my equipment with a Mikrotik router. However, after connecting my PC to the new router, IPv6 is not functioning correctly.
When monitoring the traffic in Wireshark, I observe "Router Solicitation" and "Router Advertisement" packets, but they only carry a /64 prefix. Additionally, my Linux box does not receive any DHCPv6 responses, as shown in the image below. In my conversations with the ISP, they keep insisting that their DHCP is configured correctly to provide the desired prefix, but given that I’m not receiving DHCP responses, I'm not entirely sure whether they are referring to DHCPv6 or SLAAC.

After attempting to configure IPv6 statically, the ISP tech support informed me that it’s not working because I’m connecting a PC to the router rather than another router.
My questions are:

Should the "Router Advertisement" be announcing a /56 prefix?
If the RA should announce a /56, what IPv6 address and prefix length should my Linux box assign to itself? Should it use a /56, or should it automatically create a /64 subnet from that /56?
If I assign a static IPv6 address to my Linux PC, should the prefix length be /56, /64, or /128?
Does the claim that it’s not working because I’m using a PC instead of a router make any sense?
What should I demand from them to rule out any issues on my side?

Thank you very much!

Your ISP is being moronic. (the microtik speaks loudly.) I doubt they have any clue what they're doing. If you have access to it, look at the config of the supplied router.

Unfortunately they won't provide me with the router password. But their support is friendly and I'll send them the link for this discussion so we can get this solved together.

LAN segments will normally only ever be /64's. Announcing the entire /56 via RA is a horrible way to publish a prefix - nothing will ever support this, and the announcing router will have no idea what is using any part of the prefix. (this is only made worse by the weak, non-definition of "on-link" in the spec.) DHCPv6-PD is how downstream systems learn of delegated prefixes. As nothing is answering DHCPv6, they don't have it configured - or it's ignoring your request.
There's no difference between a "PC" and a "router". Both can do exactly the same thing. (hint: that microtik router is a linux "PC", too.)
(Posting the details of the RA and DHCP request would help. There are many bits in an RA, and a DHCP request for that matter.)

Will post the details tomorrow, at the moment I'm not getting neither RA nor DHCP responses from the router.


Should the "Router Advertisement" be announcing a /56 prefix?

That is not unusual for a business network connection. You get a small prefix from which you can use IPv6 Prefix Delegation to assign /64 networks. For example, you could have multiple networks or VLANs, each with its own /64 network. A /56 prefix gives you 256 /64 networks you can use.

If the RA should announce a /56, what IPv6 address and prefix length
should my Linux box assign to itself? Should it use a /56, or should
it automatically create a /64 subnet from that /56?

Your hosts should be assigned addressing on a /64 networks. As I explained above, you get multiple /64 networks from your /56 prefix.

If I assign a static IPv6 address to my Linux PC, should the prefix
length be /56, /64, or /128?

Each host should be on at least one /64 network. Remember that IPv6 allows a host interface to be assigned to multiple networks. Your networks, with only a couple of exceptions (/127 point-to-point links and /128 loopback addresses) should all use /64.

Does the claim that it’s not working because I’m using a PC instead of
a router make any sense?

If the ISP assumes you want your own router or firewall (you need a firewall for your site), then, yes, because your own router or firewall can delegate multiple /64 IPv6 network from the provided prefix.

What should I demand from them to rule out any issues on my side?

I think you are trying to apply IPv4 thinking to IPv6. A deeper understanding of IPv6 on your part would go a long way. IPv6 is designed to give you much more addressing that the limited IPv4 addressing, and you can actually get far more networks and addresses per network than you do with IPv4.
Maybe you do not need 256 /64 networks today, but you have that. You could separate your IoT (a very good idea) on its own network to protect your production network(s). There are other reasons to separate various functions into their own networks.
